# can't permit custom params with strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, parameters, strong-parameters

I want to permit nested custom parameters but am not sure how to access them.

These are my params:

```
params=> 
  {"utf8"=>"✓",
   "authenticity_token"=>"...",
   "tracking"=>{"installation"=>"4", "code"=>[{"1"=>"one", "2"=>"two"}]},
   "action"=>"create",
   "controller"=>"admin/trackings"}
```

According to the [Strong Parameters documentation](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#nested-parameters) I tried some combinations like this:

```
def tracking_params
  params.require(:tracking).permit(:installation, code: [])
end
```

but they are not working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
def tracking_params
  params.require(:tracking).permit(:installation, {:code => []})
end
```

Comment: this returns only `{"installation"=>"2"}`for tracking_params

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried solving this on the model level? I think you just need to add:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tracking
```

Not sure what your Rails version is, but the docs for [Rails 5.1.2](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) seem to cover this