# Permit custom created params in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have already gone through following posts, without getting any satisfactory answers:

[can't permit custom params with strong parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055466/cant-permit-custom-params-with-strong-parameters)

[Permit extra params in special cases with Strong Params in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297655/permit-extra-params-in-special-cases-with-strong-params-in-rails-4)

What I want is to permit my custom created params in rails controller:

**MY CODE**

**Template**

```
= form_tag ...
  = select_tag :hour, options_for_select(options_for_hours), name: "clinic_hour[close_time][]", title: "Hours"
  = select_tag :minute, options_for_select(options_for_minutes), name: "clinic_hour[close_time][]", title: "Minutes"
  = select_tag :convention, options_for_select([["AM", "AM"], ["PM", "PM"]]), name: "clinic_hour[close_time][]"
  = submit_tag ...
```

The above code creates **params** like:

```
Parameters: {"clinic_hour"=>{"close_time"=>["0", "0", "AM"]}}
```

But in controller...

**Controller**

When I do like:

```
def clinic_hour_params
  params.require(:clinic_hour).permit(
    :close_time
  )
end
```

It still says this, in rails server log:

```
Unpermitted parameters: close_time
{}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array here, which means, you need to specifically tell to accept an array. Try this:

```
def clinic_hour_params
  params.require(:clinic_hour).permit(
    :close_time => []
  )
end
```

Also here https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters you can see which all types are "permittable".

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the README for Strong Parameters under [Permitted Scalar Values](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) you will see that since you're working with an array of scalar values you'll have to denote it like this:

```
def clinic_hour_params
  params.require(:clinic_hour).permit(
    close_time: []
  )
end
```